# QuerSet object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create a "Kriskras" that has a list of activities behind it.
so i used a foreign key to link them. but every time i am trying to add something to the list i get the error

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'vergadering_set'

this is my model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Kriskras(models.Model):
    tak = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.tak

class Vergadering(models.Model):
    kriskras = models.ForeignKey(Kriskras, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    activiteit = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activiteit
```

how can i solve it so i can use the vergadering_set attribute?

Comment: Add you code not a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are using a reverse relation with all objects which is not allowed. You can use `vergadering_set` like this:

```py
# pay attention I'm not using Kriskras.objects.all()
ls = Kriskras.objects.first() # will return first item from database.
ls.vergadering_set.all() # will return the expected result
```

You can read more about this [here in django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)